# PHP Page Load & Real-Time Variables

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get date data from a php script to the html where it displays the current time of when the page was loaded initially. And the current time updated in real-time.

I have been able to get the current time using the

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());  ...
```

But I cant find what the function is to get the time that the webpage was opened?

Any help please. Okay I made a mistake and got it switched. I have the time of page load and now I need the current time in real-time retrieved.

No worries guys, thanks for helping me on the first bit I am gonna go try and get the real-time thingy myself :)

Comment: Surely you just echo the time when the page is first loaded? Then that's the time the page was first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())` will be the time you generated the page.

For updating it real-time, you will need to use some client side code, as `PHP` only runs on the server-side.

For the real-time clock, I would suggest you to look at the `JQuery` library for `JavaScript`.

http://jquery.com/

Comment: Ah i see! So I had it the other way around. I had page load all along but not a dynamic changing current time... damn! Thanks!